# Bootstrap Model is closed everytime after click on the cancel icon in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have to remove the product from the list. My product is removed properly but after I click on the cancel icon, the model closes. I am using AngularJS.

```js
/**
 * @Summary: removeSelectedProductFromAlbum function, remove the productKey from the album
 * @param: event, index, productObject
 * @return: NA
 * @Description:
 */ 
$scope.albumKey            = [];
$scope.albumObject         = [];
$scope.setAlbumObject      = [];

$scope.removeSelectedProductFromAlbum = function(event, index, productObject) {
    //GET THE ALBUM OBJECT FROM THE SCOPE
    $scope.setAlbumObject = $scope.setAlbumObject;
    //PROCESS TO REMOVE productKeyId IN ALBUM.
    var productKeyId = productObject.keyId;
    
    if(productKeyId != undefined) {
        if($scope.productsKeyIdList != undefined && $scope.productsKeyIdList != null) {
            var index = $scope.productsKeyIdList.indexOf(productKeyId);
            $scope.productsKeyIdList.splice(index, 1);
            updatedProductKeyArray = $scope.productsKeyIdList;
            
            //Calling updateArray inner function for update sharedBuyerKeyIdList after remove the keyId
            updateArray();
        }
    } 
}
//CALLING THE updateArray FUNCTION FOR UPDATE THE PRODUCT AFTER DELETING THE DATA
function updateArray () {
    var PRODUCT_DB_REF = firebase.database().ref('datastore/productsAlbum');
    // Updating product key in album.
    PRODUCT_DB_REF.child($scope.setAlbumObject.key).update({
        productKey : updatedProductKeyArray
    });
    CMN.showNotification("top","center","info","Product is Successfully Removed");
    //$(event.currentTarget).parents("#hideAfterRemove").hide("slow");
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow:auto; max-height:300px;" >
<div class="dashboard-prod-wrap decorCardD2" 
style="width:342px;"  ng-repeat="sellerAlbum in sellerSelAlbumProducts" ng-if="sellerSelAlbumProducts.length > 0">
  <i class="fa fa-remove" style="font-size:14px; cursor:pointer;" title="Remove"
    ng-click="removeSelectedProductFromAlbum($event, $index, sellerAlbum)">
  </i>
<div class="w3-row w3-padding-top ng-cloak">
  <span class="pull-left color-d4 text-capitalize no-wrap dash-prod-name w3-small ng-cloak">
    <span class="product-name" style='padding-right:3px;'> 
      {{sellerAlbum.categoriesDto.categoryName}} 
    </span>
     &nbsp;
    <span class="w3-text-teal ng-cloak">
      <b>{{sellerAlbum.sellerProductDesignsDtos[0].designsName}}</b>
    </span>
    <span class="w3-text-teal ng-cloak" ng-if="sellerAlbum.designNumber != 'undefined'"> 
      -<b>{{sellerAlbum.designNumber}}</b>
    </span>
    <small class="text-muted w3-left w3-price-tag ng-cloak"> 
      <div class='list-icon-f'>
        <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <span ng-if="!sellerAlbum.inOffer">
        <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>
        {{sellerAlbum.fixedPrice}}
      </span>
      <span ng-if="sellerAlbum.inOffer">
        <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>
        <strike class="w3-text-red">{{sellerAlbum.fixedPrice}}</strike> 
          <span class="w3-text-green"> 
            {{sellerAlbum.offerPrice}}
          </span>
      </span>
    </small>
    <small class="text-muted w3-left w3-price-tag ng-cloak" ng-if="sellerAlbum.fixedPrice == 0"> 
      <div class='list-icon-f'>
        <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <span ng-if="!sellerAlbum.inOffer">
        <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>
        {{sellerAlbum.maxPrice}} 
      </span>
      <span ng-if="sellerAlbum.inOffer">
        <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>
        <strike class="w3-text-red">{{sellerAlbum.maxPrice}}</strike> 
          <strong class="w3-text-green">
            {{sellerAlbum.offerPrice}}
          </strong>
      </span>
      <small class="w3-small"> (<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>{{sellerAlbum.minPrice}}
        - <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>{{sellerAlbum.maxPrice}})
      </small>
    </small>
  </span>
  <div class="pull-right ng-cloak" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;">
    <div class='owner-img'>
      <img src="{{sellerAlbum.sellerDto.userTypeDto.imageURL != 'null' ? sellerAlbum.sellerDto.userTypeDto.imageURL : '/static/assets/img/image_placeholder.jpg'}}"
        alt="Avatar" class="w3-right w3-circle w3-margin-left">
    </div> 
    <small class="text-uppercase w3-tiny text-muted text-right ng-cloak">
      <b>{{sellerAlbum.sellerDto.personName}}</b>
      <span  ng-repeat="address in sellerAlbum.sellerDto.userTypeDto.userTypeAddressDtos"
          ng-if="address.keyId === sellerAlbum.sellerDto.userTypeDto.defaultAddressKeyId">
         - <b>{{address.city}}</b>
      </span><br>
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
<hr class="w3-clear margin0">
<div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-top" style="margin: 0 -16px">
  <!-- START:This will display Large Product Image -->
  <div class="dashboard-prod-col-left w3-center">
    <div class="text-center  w3-padding-8"
      ng-init="setImageURLList[sellerAlbum.keyId] = sellerAlbum.sellerProductSetDto[0].setImageURLList">
      <div ng-repeat="image in setImageURLList[sellerAlbum.keyId]"
        ng-click="sellerAlbum.defaultImageURL = image.imageURL"
        onClick="imgShadowArr(this);"
        ng-init="sellerAlbum.defaultImageURL = setImageURLList[sellerAlbum.keyId][0].imageURL"
        class="dashboard-prod-img-wrap {{sellerAlbum.defaultImageURL == image.imageURL ? 'w3-border-teal-orange' : ''}}">
        <img src="{{image.imageURL}}" class="prod-img-xs cursor-pointer">
      </div>
      <div class="dashboard-prod-img-wrap"
        ng-if="productImgsList[sellerAlbum.keyId].length < 1">
        <img src="/static/assets/img/product_default.jpg"
          class="prod-img-xs">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END:This will display Large Product Image -->
  <div class="dashboard-prod-col-right w3-center hover-div">
    <img src="{{sellerAlbum.sellerProductSetDto[0].setImageURLList[0].imageURL != null ? sellerAlbum.sellerProductSetDto[0].setImageURLList[0].imageURL :'/static/assets/img/product_default.jpg'}}"
      class="cursor-pointer" style="max-height:200px;border:1px solid black;">
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="">
  <div class="text-center pull-left ng-cloak list-by-a list-by-color">
    <div class='list-icon'>
      <i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class='margin0'>
      <li class="prodColorWrap" ng-repeat="productSet in sellerAlbum.sellerProductSetDto track by $index" 
        style="cursor:pointer; background-color:{{productSet.colorCode}}"
        ng-click="setImageURLList[productSet.keyId] = sellerAlbum.setImageURLList; 
          productSet.defaultImageURL = setImageURLList[productSet.keyId][0].imageURL">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='w3-offer-tag' ng-if="sellerAlbum.inOffer">
    <label>
      <i class="fa fa-star w3-spin"></i> 
        Offer
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
</div>
```

function for remove icon , please sir how to fix this issue?

Comment: try to add
event.preventDefault()
event.stopPropagation()
to the removeSelectedProductFromAlbum

Comment: Sir, in which position i have to used this code?

Comment: You have removeSelectedProductFromAlbum function that have evente e as an argument. Add this code there.

Comment: Like this :- $scope.removeSelectedProductFromAlbum = function(event, index, productObject) {
   event.preventDefault(); }

Comment: sir i am using event.preventDefault but  preventDefault  is unefined here?

Comment: check pls event object in debugger

Comment: sir event is find..sir i am using event.stopPropagation()  but model is close again?

Comment: pls use both - preventDefault and stopPropagation

Comment: does this help?

Comment: Like this i am right sir :- $scope.removeSelectedProductFromAlbum = function(event, index, productObject) {     event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();}

Comment: sir i am using both function but model is closed again what can i do for fix this ?